# Getting Null object reference in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to load the list of schools from sqlite database and show it in autocomplete textview in that i am getting an null object error.I have loaded the sqlite data from asset folder since the data are too high i have loaded it from assests folder.

Code:

```
public class Profileeditpage extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{
    EditText name,email;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    List<Schoolname> nameschool;
    AutoCompleteTextView grade,location,schoolname;
    Toolbar mtool;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));

    String[] grad={"Grade1","Grade2","Grade3","Grade4","Grade5","Grade6","Grade7"};
    private static final String TAG = Profileeditpage.class.getSimpleName();
    Schoolname currentq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editprofile);
        mtool=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtool);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        SchoolDatabaseHelper db=new SchoolDatabaseHelper(this);
        db.openDatabase();
        nameschool=getAllSchools();

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtprofilename);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtprofilemail);
        location = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edtlocation);
        schoolname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvschoolname);
        grade = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvgrade);


       // schoolname.setThreshold(1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,grad);
        grade.setThreshold(0);
        grade.setDropDownWidth(-1);

        grade.setDropDownVerticalOffset(5);
        grade.setAdapter(adapter);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Profileeditpage.this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
        location.setThreshold(1);
        location.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);
        location.setDropDownWidth(-1);
        location.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);


    }

    public List<Schoolname> getAllSchools() {
        List<Schoolname>nameschool= new ArrayList<Schoolname>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT schoolname FROM schooldet ORDER BY schoolname ASC";
        //db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Schoolname quest = new Schoolname();
                quest.setNames(cursor.getString(0));
                nameschool.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list

        String[] stockArr = new String[nameschool.size()];
        stockArr = nameschool.toArray(stockArr);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,stockArr);
        schoolname.setAdapter(sadapter);

        return nameschool;
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };
    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            CharSequence attributions = places.getAttributions();


        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connected.");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
}
```

Database:

```
public class SchoolDatabaseHelper extends Activity{
    private static final String DB_NAME = "school.sqlite";

    private Context context;

    public SchoolDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);

        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {
                SQLiteDatabase checkDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                if(checkDB != null){

                    checkDB.close();

                }
                copyDatabase(dbFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            }
        }

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer);
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
        at nidhinkumar.gridcam.logindetails.Profileeditpage.getAllSchools(Profileeditpage.java:104)
        at nidhinkumar.gridcam.logindetails.Profileeditpage.onCreate(Profileeditpage.java:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
```

Comment: Uncomment `//db = this.getReadableDatabase();`

Answer (score 0):

The member variable `db` is not initialized. In your init method you create a local variable, which is not accessible from the method `getAllSchools()`

So try something like this:

```
SchoolDatabaseHelper db =new SchoolDatabaseHelper(this);
this.db = db.getReadableDatabase();
nameschool=getAllSchools();
```